# How can I improve timepicker speed in Android?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I design a android timepicker layout :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZOzm.jpg)

In fact , there are six timepicker in on layout ,
I find it's too slow ,

how can I improve timepicker speed ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with 6 time pickers on same screen? May be you consider to redesign it in a different way.

Comment: Our customers say six timepicker will easy to understand set up.

Comment: Sorry but I asked "What do you want to achieve", so I still don't know the answer.

Comment: For example , One device need to start at 8:00 and end at 9:00 am , then it's will start again at 13:00 , end at 13:30 . final , it's will sart at 21:00 and end at 22:00 , so there are six timepicker.